# tradingview's pine scrip's "display.status_line" is not even available

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wanted to remove 2 values from my indicator's status line, i referenced  it on the reference guide it says like this `display (plot_display)` Controls where the plot's information is displayed.

Display options support addition and subtraction, meaning that using `display.all - display.status_line` will display the plot's information everywhere except in the script's status line. But this is not working for me

Code:

```
   plotshape(buy, title = "long", size = 'normal', color = color.green, style = shape.arrowup, location = location.belowbar, display = display.all - display.status_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your chart settings are correct.

You should enable the "Scales" option "Indicators and financials value labels".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

that answer is clearly the opposite of what he wants to do.
They are trying to NOT show something on their chart. Your answer tells them how to fully make things show on ALL charts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).